# Jmeter use Selenium javascript webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

All the examples show how to use Selenium Java webdriver with Jmeter.

Can I use Selenium Javascript webdriver with Jmeter?

Comment: Why would you use Selenium with Jmeter?

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler

Comment: your question is too broad, you should indicate your purpose here. But if you are just looking for a straight answer, then the answer is yes you can use Selenium with JMeter.

Comment: I am trying to make Selenium work with Jmeter. All the examples I see and the Jmeter plugin for Selenium is for webdriver Java. I wanted to know if there is a plugin for webdriver Javascript for Jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is default language of the [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)

[image: WebDriver Sampler JavaScript]

so the answer is **yes**, you can use JavaScript language for Selenium tests with the WebDriver Sampler.

Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for some code snippets, howtos, tips and tricks

Comment: There's also a short video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5U-q3ATfb8).